# Устранение смещения в выборке

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Задача линейной регрессии. Есть генеральная совокупность. Со смещением (свободный член не равен нулю). Размер выборки - порядка 350 наблюдений. 15 независимых параметров. Выборка содержит трудно выявляемые выбросы.

Как сформировать из генеральной совокупности выборку без смещения?

Буду признателен за здравые мыcли и образцы кода.

Comment: Не уверен, что вы правильно трактуете термин "смещение выборки". Вообще почитайте про регуляризацию и про фильтрацию выбросов, лишним не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [RobustScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html) - он устойчив к выбросам. Собственно для этого он и был создан - для нормализации данных с выбросами.

В описании метода есть пример использования:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
>>> X = [[ 1., -2.,  2.],
...      [ -2.,  1.,  3.],
...      [ 4.,  1., -2.]]
>>> transformer = RobustScaler().fit(X)
>>> transformer
RobustScaler()
>>> transformer.transform(X)
array([[ 0. , -2. ,  0. ],
       [-1. ,  0. ,  0.4],
       [ 1. ,  0. , -1.6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Cудя по вопросу - вы не разобрались с тем что такое выбросы, что такое смещение регрессионной модели и как они между собой связаны(или нет).

Начнем с того, что смешение (в данном контексте!) есть свойство модели, а не генеральной совокупности. Т.е. есть совокупность объектов, вы строите ее модель линейной регрессии получаете выражение вида Y_мод=X*A+b. Однако возможно и вполне законно искать модель не среди пространства всех возможных линейных одночленов, а в пространстве линейных одночленов с нулевым свободным членом. Т.е. получить в результате модель вида Y_мод=X*A.

В sklearn функция LinearRegression имеет параметр fit_intercept. Задав ему значение False
вы как раз и получаете функцию без свободного члена. Задав значение True (по умолчанию) получаете модель со свободным членом.

Обратите внимание, что обе модели строятся на одних и тех-же данных и обе модели абсолютно корректны с математической точки зрения -  при соответственных ограничениях. См. картинку, на которой видно две эти модели одновременно, построенных по одним данным.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К вопросу выбросов это не имеет никакого отношения.  Выброс - это такие точки, которые в некотором смысле существенно отличаются от остальных. Например, по отклонению от модельного значения. В таком контексте одна и та-же точка может быть выбросом для модели со свободным членом и не быть таковым для модели с нулевым свободным членом или наоборот. Имеются и другие подходы к определению того, что считать выбросом. Их много и разных, и выбор метода - весьма нетривиальная задача.

Имеется и другая трактовка термина "смещение" выборки. А именно - регулярное изменение некоторой статистики выборки относительно аналогичной статистики генеральной совокупности. Самый известный пример - смещенность параметра стандартного отклонения выборки относительно дисперсии генеральной совокупности. Что решается в данном, простейшем, случае введением знаменателя (n-1) известного из элементарного курса матстатистики. В данном случае "смещение" - это опять свойство метода, а не выборки. Хотя задача формирования "несмещенной" выборки в данном контексте может ставиться, но отношения к регрессионной модели и к выявлению выбросов она не имеет.

Из всего сказанного становиться понятным, что вопрос "сформировать из генеральной совокупности выборку без смещения" становиться лишенным смысла. Можно ставить вопрос - отобрать данные, отбросив точки-выбросы. Но это совсем другая задача. Так что - определитесь, пожалуйста.